# Pyside2 добавить тулбары в табы

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyside2, qtoolbar

В приложении есть табы.
Как на каждый таб добавить тулбары?

**app.py**

```
from UI_test import Ui_Form
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import qdarkgraystyle
import sys

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    app.setStyleSheet(qdarkgraystyle.load_stylesheet())
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UI_test.py**

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt,QPointF
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(1900, 920)
        self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab1.setObjectName("tab1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "tab1")

        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2.setObjectName("tab2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab2, "tab2")

        self.grid_main = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.grid_main.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        Form.setLayout(self.grid_main)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

```
import sys
#import qdarkgraystyle
'''
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt,QPointF
from PySide2.QtCharts import QtCharts
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


# from UI_test import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tabWidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.tabWidget.setMinimumSize(600, 420)
        self.tabWidget.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab1.setObjectName("tab1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab1, "tab1")

        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2.setObjectName("tab2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab2, "tab2")

        self.grid_main = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.grid_main.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        Form.setLayout(self.grid_main)
        
 
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.infos = {
            "Tab 3": ('Test 3', 'img/qt-logo.png'),
            "Tab 4": ('Test 4', 'Ok.png'),
            "Tab 5": ('Test 5', 'im.png'),
        }
        for name in self.infos:
            self.create_widgets(name)

    def create_widgets(self, name):
        window = QMainWindow()
        self.tabWidget.addTab(window, name)
        basicToolBar = window.addToolBar('Basic')
        basicToolBar.addAction(self.infos[name][0])
        basicToolBar.addAction(QIcon(self.infos[name][1]), name)
        tab = QTabWidget()
        window.setCentralWidget(tab)
        for i in range(5):
            tab.addTab(QWidget(), f"{name}: tab-{i}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
#    app.setStyleSheet(qdarkgraystyle.load_stylesheet())
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Собственно, я так и думал, для каждого таба создается окно...Подскажите еще,пожалуйста, как на кноку в тулбаре повесить вызов функции?

Comment: @Newman задайте новый вопрос, приложите код, напишите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Поменял строчку basicToolBar.addAction(QtGui.QIcon('back2.png'), 'tab2',Form.test_tool) ,где  "test_tool" - вызов функции